# Script. Delete temp mozilla firefox

Tags: batch-file

The point is that I have to create a script for my school that deletes all the temporary ones from Mozilla Firefox, with a batch script in Windows 10.
The most complex thing about this is that the mozilla path has a folder that has a different "Prefix" on each computer, in my case it is
**wvbrz602**.default-release.
(Ruta completa sería: *C:\Users\dmarmol\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\wvbrz602.default-release*)

What I have done has been a loop that iterates for each user and stores it in the variable in which it iterates "**%%a**" In this way I obtain each user, once each user is obtained, I do a **dir** obtaining the prefix of the containing folder of the **Firefox** profile of each user in a **.txt** document (Since the prefix is ​​different for each user)
After that **prefix** obtained in the **.txt** of each user I add it to a variable (The problem is that, apparently they don't like it)
And finally I make a **del** of the temporary of each user.

This is my code:

```
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
rem TASKKILL /F /IM mozilla.exe /T

for /f %%a in ('dir c:\Users /b') do>%%a.txt (
dir /b "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default-release"
set /p contenedorFor=<"%%a".txt
del C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%contenedorFor%\cache2

)
exit /b 0
```

I show a snapshot of the exit the code.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfe2p.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply test if the file exists. Here, the result will be `echo`'ed only where you need to replace `echo` with `rmdir` or `del` accordingly:

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("%systemdrive%\Users\*") do (
     for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "%%~i\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" 2^>nul ^|findstr "default-release"') do del /Q "%%~i\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%%~nxa\Cache2\*"
)
```

Comment: It finds the path but when I do a del it doesn't find the path. I will keep trying with the help you have given me. :S

Comment: it won't because it only `echo`'s the path like I mentioned in the post. Is `cache2` a file or directory? That will make the difference in whether you need `del` or `rmdir`

Comment: It's a directory, with del has to all files inside cache2

Comment: try code as edited.

Comment: It does not work, "The system cannot find the specified file" :S

Comment: Then `Cache2` simply does not exist in `..AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` ? Please show me the exact path of the `Cache2` dir

Comment: Exact path -> C:\Users\dmarmol\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\wvbrz602.default-release\cache2

Comment: If I do del /Q "%%~i\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ all there is inside the directory Profiles, it removes it all files, but, does not like a del /Q "%%~i\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cache2\

If I put del /Q "%%~i\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\wvbrz602.default-release\" it find it, but back to the main question: Each user has a different name, in my case wvbrz602.default-release

Comment: So that is why, we never included the default.release path. I do not have Mozilla so I have to work of your examples.

Comment: My problem is it.. the path default.release....

Comment: YES! Now if you add /s to comand del, remove all files inside directory and subdirectory. Thanks us for help. Can you explain to me this sentence ( 2^>nul ^ )  ?

Comment: `>` redirects output to either a file or to `nul`. Where `nul` is an internal nowhere on the system. there are 2 particular streams we're interested in `stdout` (or standard output) and `stderr` (which is the error stream). here we simply say redirect the error stream output to `nul` `2` is `stderr` and `1` is `stdout`. I implemented it here simply to not display any user profiles that does not have the `Mozilla\Profiles` directories because we're not interested in those.

Comment: Great! From the bottom of my heart, thank you for your help and your time.